# Retrofit continue work in browser (response as html page)

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm working with a bank api. When user chooses to add his bank card to his account I need to make request to their API and then continue in browser for user to enter his card credentials in https safety

API looks like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/jsp/hbpay/logon.jsp")
Observable<Response<String>> addCard(@Field("Signed_Order_B64") String order,
                                   @Field("email") String email,
                                   @Field("Language") String lang,
                                   @Field("BackLink") String backLink,
                                   @Field("PostLink ") String postLink,
                                   @Field("FailureBackLink") String failureBackLink);
```

BackLink and others are supposed to be web links to send user in different situations. I don't know what to put there for android.

Next, I have my request:

```
private void addCardRequest() {
    showProgress();
    mDisposable.add(createAddCardOrder()
            .flatMap(orderString -> mBankApi.addCard(orderString,
                    mDataManager.getLocalUserInfo().getEmail(),
                    BankApi.EPAY_LANG,
                    BankApi.EPAY_BACK_LINK,//"http://localhost/"?
                    BankApi.EPAY_POST_LINK,
                    BankApi.EPAY_FAILURE_BACK_LINK))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::handleAddCardResponse,
                    this::handleError,
                    () -> Timber.w("addCard completed")));
}
```

Response is a plain html page with a bunch of pics and scripts. What I'm doing for now is just saving it as a .html file and then displaying in a webview:

```
private void handleAddCardResponse(Response<String> response) throws Exception {
    hideProgress();
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        String fileUrl = getContext().getCacheDir() + "/add_card.html";
        Utils.writeStringToFile(getContext(), response.body(), fileUrl);
        startActivity(WebViewActivity.getIntent(getContext(), fileUrl));
    } else {
        throw handleUnsuccessfulResponse(response);
    }
}
```

What I need is to open incoming response (which is a html markup) in browser, or to make the browser make my request and handle response

Comment: Hello, To add it to your API, get a sample from the bank support/developer/portal  regarding the API, every such api are almost the same but they still do differ a bit. I believe this isnt enough of info u have.

Comment: There are samples for web applications, most of the documentation cover building the request. There are no samples regarding the issue.

Comment: You cannot directly integrate a bank api like that, you need to have a payment gateway, and a Vendor account in process. checkout CC avenue, PayU etc.

Comment: If your bank provides such api , you need to get either a rest base api, or a custom Android Module implimentation from Them

Comment: we have a working web client application, now my job is to make an android version of it. there is a rest API (I showed retrofit interface of it), which I'm using. I can get cards and delete cards, but can't add cards yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was supposed to call this in WebViewActivity:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.postUrl(POST_URL, postData.getBytes());
```

postData builds like this:

```
private String buildPostData(String order64) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode("Signed_Order_B64", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(order64, "UTF-8")
                + "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode("Language", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(BankApi.EPAY_LANG, "UTF-8")
                + "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode("BackLink", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(BankApi.EPAY_BACK_LINK, "UTF-8")
                + "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode("FailureBackLink", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(BankApi.EPAY_FAILURE_BACK_LINK, "UTF-8")
                + "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode("PostLink", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(BankApi.EPAY_POST_LINK, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

MyWebViewClient should look like this, so it would capture url links:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Timber.w("URL loading = %s", url);

        if (BankApi.EPAY_POST_LINK.equals(url)) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
            return true;
        } else if (BankApi.EPAY_BACK_LINK.equals(url)) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
            return true;
        } else if (BankApi.EPAY_FAILURE_BACK_LINK.equals(url)) {
            setResult(RESULT_FAILURE);
            finish();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and then just call startActivityForResult and listen to result